# Flip Flop frequency divider by 17

Tags: flipflop, frequency-divider

I have a task to make frequency divider by 12, 17, 30. I have figured out how to make divider by 12 using staging dividers by 6 and staging dividers by 10. But 17 is odd number and i can't make it like others two.
Like on the image using staging flip-flops with divider by 2 and by 6 i can get division by 12.

[image: d flip flop divider]

Comment: What technology are you using for this exercise? 12 and 30 both have odd factors. Add the information into your question (not in the comments).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *But 17 is odd number and i can't make it like others two*

If you want a **rough and ready** circuit, the old and well-trodden "divide by \$2^n - 1\$" method using an exclusive OR gate should be sufficient. So you can can make a divide-by-three using a divide-by-four circuit and one exclusive or gate. Then cascade this with a divide-by-6 circuit and you have a divide-by-18 circuit. Using the same exclusive or gate trick this can be made into a divide by 17. Schematic of divide-by-three: -

[image]

Waveforms: -

[image]

As you can see the Vout waveform (red) is the input clock (blue) divided by three. So, if you want a divide-by-six then use a divide-by-eight and two exor gates: -

[image]

[image]

As you can see the above circuit takes a divide by-eight and, using two exclusive or gates, turns it into a divide-by-six.

So, cascade the divide-by-three and the divide-by-six to make a divide-by-eighteen then, using another exclusive or gate make it a divide-by-seventeen: -

[image]

[image]

The above is a divide-by-seventeen circuit.

> *I have a task to make frequency divider by 12, 17, 30*

I think you should be able to figure out the divide-by-thirty for yourself but, if you need help, leave a comment.

Comment: Thank you, thats a detailed answer!

Comment: Hope it helps you.

Comment: @Andyaka could you by any chance recommend  a literature explaining "divide by 2^n−1" method? I've successfully used your example to make divide-by-11 circuit but I am not sure I understand the theory behind flip-flop & XOR combination.

Comment: @IvanDemyachenko I learnt this technique some time in the early 1980s so unfortunately I have no links to what it was that I read nor can I remember what it was. Theory is simple, the XOR adds an extra clock cycle to the counter and you can see this in the waveforms I provided. Please feel free to upvote if you found it useful.